# How to make transaction in java to delete two tables?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am working with DB2 Database
and I want to make a transaction to delete both tables synchronously , in one transaction

So How can I do that by java

```
 String SQL  =" DELETE  FROM     CUSTOMERS;";
          Statement stmt= connection.createStatement();
          stmt.executeUpdate(SQL );

  SQL =" DELETE  FROM    Products ;";
          Statement stmt= connection.createStatement();
          stmt.executeUpdate(SQL );
```

I think this is not transaction
I need a way to make it with transaction commands

Comment: Do you mean like `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the start?

Comment: How about creating a stored procedure and calling it?

Comment: OK ! could you give me an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` to start a transaction, then when you've executed your SQL statements use `connection.commit();` to finish the transaction (or `connection.rollback()` if something went wrong).

You might also want to use a "truncate table" statement instead (i.e. `TRUNCATE TABLE CUSTOMERS`
), it should be faster than delete if you want to empty the whole table.

Comment: I need an example please

Comment: Put connection.setAutoCommit(false) at the beginning and connection.commit() at the end.

Comment: And use `connection.rollback()` in the `catch` block in order to rollback the operation in case of errors.

Comment: How can I pass 2 Queries to the connection

Comment: @Maria One after another of course. Also read the JDBC tutorial, you seem to have skipped it.